# Is there a way of preventing a C++ compiler from optimizing a copy of a temporary rvalue into a move operation?

Tags: c++, optimization, move, rvalue, temporary

eg:

```
std::vector<int> i;
i = std::vector{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
```

In the above case, a compiler will typically optimize the second line into a move operation instead of a copy operation despite the lack of a std::move() enclosure. This is normally fine, but in some cases can cause issues, for example, if `i` is declared with a particular allocator, the semantics of what happens with the destination allocator is very different, depending on whether or not the operation is a copy or a move (if the vector implementation is standards-compliant, that is).
Let's ignore that the above is Bad Code ie. it should be one line, without the needless construction of a secondary vector and focus on the other problem.

We could hypothesize other use-cases where moving is designed to do something slightly different with container metadata. Say we have a struct:

```
struct t
{
   int data;
   int usage;

   // Methods and constructors etc go here
};
```

And the `usage` variable tells us how many times the `data` has been accessed by a given method. Semantically, a copy operation would probably simply copy the `data` variable from one struct instance to another. A move operation would want to replace the `usage` variable as well, as it is effectively moving the entire state of one struct instance to another. Ignore whether or not you think this is unlikely, it's just a hypothetical example for illustration purposes.

Now, if someone writes some bad code eg.:

```
t a;
// Some accesses of a's data member occur here via a member function.

t b = 4;
a = b;
// b is not used after this point.
```

The compiler may optimize b into a temporary, and optimize `a = b` into a move operation. As noted, this could cause problems.

So.
Is there a way - from the writer of the struct's side - to write `operator =` methods such that both copy assignment and move assignment are possible, but that the C++ compiler cannot optimize the copy operation into a move operation - even if a temporary rvalue is used? I'm aware this can be prevented by the writer of the code using `t`, but I'm interested in fool-proofing code in this particular case.

Thanks-

Comment: _"The compiler may optimize b into a temporary, and optimize `a = b` into a move operation. As noted, this could cause problems."_ No, it may not.  `b` is an lvalue.  No such optimization is allowed here.

Comment: Does `-std=c++98 -fno-elide-constructors -pedantic` help? (the no-eliding constructor part is just for good measure)

Comment: Some parts of this question sound like you're misunderstanding what `std::move` is. `std::move` is effectively just a cast to rvalue reference. It doesn't mean "use the move constructor/move assignment operator". When you do `i = std::vector{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}`, the compiler isn't optimizing a copy into a move; it's picking a move because that's what the C++ overload resolution rules say this should resolve to.

Comment: I highly recommend reviewing how `std::move` and `std::forward` work with rvalues like xvalues and prvalues and especially forwarding references. There's some good videos on cppcon's youtube channel. It can, and often clearly is confusing, but once you get what and why things are the way they are you will have no problems with it in the future.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for that, I wasn't aware of it. Unfortunate that these pitfalls exist in c++